# Vite/react showing blank page

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, frontend, backend, vite

I'm useing vite react to make simple site and it all the time is working good but after I have running **Local wordpress site** after this he shows me blank page, I have wapplyzer extension is shows CMC is Wordpress and PROGRAMMING LANG is PHP.

I hope someone can help me

NOTES: I'm in development environment.

I try to change host & port for vite server but still not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Perform the following checks that could help you find the cause and solution to the problem:**

1 - Open the browser's developer tools (pressing F12 or right-clicking and selecting "Inspect") and go to the Console tab and check if there are any error messages or warnings. This can give you clues about what might be causing the issue.

2 - If WordPress and your Vite/React application both include JavaScript libraries, there might be conflicts. Make sure there are no naming conflicts or incompatible libraries causing issues.

3 - Temporarily disable any WordPress plugins that might be interacting with your site. Sometimes, plugins can conflict with JavaScript and cause issues.

Comment: Thanks, man. I'm stupid. I forgot the console. There are 7 problems that I solved and the code worked , Thanks.